# How to merge many csv files in one file contains many sheets each sheet is for one csv file

Tags: python, csv, merge

I am looking to merge many CSV files in one CSV files contains many sheets. Each sheet represents one CSV file. The number of rows and columns in CSV files are not the same. In other words, one of CSV files contains one row and the other one contains 25 rows.

For example:

CSV file1:

```
  X1           X2     X3      X4       X5
4.871875    5.46875   0   0 5.19375  5.7296875
5.9765625   6.45625   0   0 6.23125  6.6984375
6.9421875   7.4140625 0   0 7.178125 7.65625
```

CSV file 2:

```
    T1          T2
0.4765625   49.00299974
```

CSV file 3:

```
  F1      F2         F3          F4       F5            F6          F8           F9         F10
1.0375  0.96875 1.275461305 1.330428703 0.5015625   0.4671875   1.307985822 1.290065155 39.45783133
  F11            F12        F13         F14         F15 
41.4516129  39.45783133 41.4516129  8.885542169 6.774193548   


 F1      F2         F3          F4       F5            F6          F8           F9         F10
1.03    0.9686  1.2754454   1.33044545  0.50135 0.4671525   1.30768822  1.26785155  39.456456133
  F11            F12           F13          F14            F15 
41.45187129 39.457675133    41.45173129 8.8858345542169 6.774874548
```

I want to merge these CSV files in one CSV file (CSV file 4) with many sheets:

- sheet 1 includes CSV file 1
- sheet 2 includes CSV file 2
- sheet 2 includes CSV file 3

I would be happy if you can advise me in how to do that.

Comment: Since CSV files are plain text files, not spreadsheet files, I'm assuming you mean creating one Excel file that contains multiple sheets?

Comment: Thank you so much, Cavin. I am looking to create one csv file contains many sheets, but I understood from you that I can't creat a spreadsheets for a csv file.

Comment: I am already created many spreadsheets for one Excel file.

Comment: So, a CSV file can only have on sheet, not multiple sheets. It's a type of text file, which can have only one sheet, not an Excel file, which can have one sheet or multiple sheets.